# How to play rtmp url live streaming in flowplayer

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flowplayer, rtmp, live-streaming

Use this code..first time it is play rtmp live streaimg.but now,This Player is loaded only.No play

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    clip: {  
        url: 'livestream',
        provider: 'rtmp',
        live: true
    },
    plugins: {
        // RTMP streaming plugin
        rtmp: {
            url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://domain.com/hiox'
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me

Comment: Please correct indentation of your code and double check the syntax. This will help you getting an answer

Comment: How is your stream called on encoder side? With .flv at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, according to the Edgecast documentation you should use the subscribe parameter:

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    clip: {  
        url: 'livestream',
        provider: 'rtmp',
        live: true
    },
    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
            url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://domain.com/hiox',
            subscribe: true
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Fixed typo.

Answer (score 2):

I think your URL is wrong as well as check out your streaming server, In my case it is red5. 
Nowadays android and ios not supporting flash. So use HLS or Dash instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Basic RTMP with red5 : Flowplayer</title>

    </head>

<body>

<div id="wowza" style="width:644px;height:276px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center; background-color: red;">
</div>
 <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
<script>
$f("wowza", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {

    clip: {
        //here the url is the link on which streaming is on
        url: 'rtmp://000.00.208.207/live/141769?key=141769',
        scaling: 'fit',
        provider: 'red5'
    },

    plugins: { 
        red5: {
        // here red5 is the streaming server, change if your server name is other
            url: "flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf",
             // netConnectionUrl defines where the streams are found
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://000.00.208.207/live/'
        }
    },
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the [RTMP docs](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html).

I have used flowplayer successfully for live streaming in the past. The difference between my config and yours is I have "subscribe: true" in my rtmp section. This was with EdgeCast as my rtmp server but other providers expect it as well.